# Saving or Creating a Parse File in Parse Cloud code

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to create a Parse cloud code function that would run a query and then put the results of the query in csv file and finally using the mailgun plugin send it out to a receipient.

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to create a Parse File in cloud code. Suggestions?

```
Parse.cloud.define("exportDataViaEmail", function(request, response){
    var query = new Parse.Query("Diaper");

    var today = new Date();
    var startTime = new Date(today - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (7*52+1));
    query.lessThan("logCreationDate", today);
    query.greaterThan("logCreationDate", startTime);
    query.find({
    success: {
    //TODO I want store this in a Parse File but how? 
    },
    error :{

    }
    });

})
/*
 * Send email via mailgun
 */

 Parse.Cloud.define("sendEmail", function(request, response){

         Mailgun.sendEmail({
          to: "myemail@gmail.com",
          from: "hello@example.com",
          subject: "Hello From example App",
          text: "Using Parse and Mailgun is great!"
        }, {
          success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse);
            response.success("Email sent!");
          },
          error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error(httpResponse);
            response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
          }
        });

 })
```

Comment: Please show your efforts. It's never fun to do others people work for them and to find out it's something they've already tried

Comment: see the todo portion.. I cannot find Parse.File or mechanism to create a Parse file

Answer (score 0):

Using files in cloud code is easy and is thoroughly documented in the [Parse Javascript Guide](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#files)

It's as simple as `var file = new Parse.File("myfile.txt", bytes);`

Comment: It certainly does. In order for me to give a more meaningful response, please include errors you may be receiving or why you're having problems. As documented in the guide, Parse.File objects can only be initialized with: (1) an Array of byte value Numbers, (2) an Object like { base64: "..." } with a base64-encoded String, or (3) a File object selected with a file upload control

Comment: I am trying to do neither. I want to create a new file with the query results stored in csv format. I was able to hack it anyhow by using chained promises and returning the json object to my server which sends out the files instead of parse.com. If you can tell me a way to do that on parse.com cloud code it would be great.

Comment: Your original question is a bit deceiving because you don't need or want to mess with Parse Files at all. Look at the Mailgun or Mandrill APIs to see how to properly set attachments for emails. For instance, with Mandrill you need to encode attachments in base64. Write your own function to structure your CSV however you like using the query results, then encode it using base64, and set the attachment according to the API. See: https://www.parse.com/questions/email-attachment-with-cloud-code and http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-mandrill-cloud-module-for-transactional-emails/

Comment: Yeah I get that... a Parse.File class for cloud code would be really helpful

Comment: There *is* a Parse.File class for cloud code, you just don't need to use it for what you're trying to do and I can't tell if you're seeing the difference. If you're requesting that there was a cloud function to convert a PFObject to CSV, that's a very simple function to make and different apps may require a specific structuring of the CSV. I hope this is helpful and clarifies what needs to happen.